# Using a thread within onDraw()

Tags: android, multithreading, ondraw

I am writing an App and I have a custom view. In this custom view I have to calculate the positions of an undetermined number of points. The number of points depends on what I am reading from my database (so it's differently for each user). 
So, my question is, how can I solve this in a good way? The steps of the app are as following:

1. Activity starts
2. Database query
3. Drawing

The problem is that the `onDraw()`-method is called when I open the activity, but I can't draw anything since I have to wait for the database-query and the calculation of the points. How can I use a Thread and maybe something like a progressbar till the calculation is done? Can i prevent the app from running the `onDraw()`-method immediately when the activity starts?

I appreciate your help.

edit1: So here is the code (Note: I didn't want to calculate anything by now, the errors appear because I try to set the visibility of the ProgressBar to true, without this line it works):

```
    public class MyView extends View {
    private ProgressBar progressBar;
    private boolean calculationsDone;

    public MyView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
            super(context);
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

            progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
            calculationsDone=false;
        }

    protected void onDraw(final Canvas canvas) {
            super.onDraw(canvas);


            if(calculationsDone == true){
                //draw stuff
                progressBar.setVisibility(INVISIBLE);
            }else{
                Log.d("calcNotDone", "CALCULATION NOT DONE YET!");
                progressBar.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
            }

        }

    }
```

Here are the Errors:

> 03-31 20:45:44.131: E/AndroidRuntime(27445): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   03-31 20:45:44.131: E/AndroidRuntime(27445):
>   java.lang.NullPointerException 03-31 20:45:44.131:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(27445):  at
>   com.example.test.MyView.onDraw(MyView.java:50) 03-31 20:45:44.131:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(27445):  at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14853)
>   03-31 20:45:44.131: E/AndroidRuntime(27445):  at
>   android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13744) 03-31 20:45:44.131:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(27445):  at
>   android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13786) 03-31 20:45:44.131:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(27445):  at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14563)
>   03-31 20:45:44.131: E/AndroidRuntime(27445):  at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3316) 03-31
>   20:45:44.131: E/AndroidRuntime(27445):    at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3153) 03-31
>   20:45:44.131: E/AndroidRuntime(27445):    at
>   android.view.View.draw(View.java:14856) 03-31 20:45:44.131:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(27445):  at
>   android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13744) 03-31 20:45:44.131:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(27445):  at
>   android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13786) 03-31 20:45:44.131:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(27445):  at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14563)
>   03-31 20:45:44.131: E/AndroidRuntime(27445):  at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3316) 03-31
>   20:45:44.131: E/AndroidRuntime(27445):    at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3153) 03-31
>   20:45:44.131: E/AndroidRuntime(27445):    at
>   android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13739) 03-31 20:45:44.131:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(27445):  at
>   android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13786) 03-31 20:45:44.131:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(27445):  at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14563)
>   03-31 20:45:44.131: E/AndroidRuntime(27445):  at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3316) 03-31
>   20:45:44.131: E/AndroidRuntime(27445):    at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3153) 03-31
>   20:45:44.131: E/AndroidRuntime(27445):    at
>   android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13739) 03-31 20:45:44.131:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(27445):  at
>   android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13786) 03-31 20:45:44.131:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(27445):  at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14563)
>   03-31 20:45:44.131: E/AndroidRuntime(27445):  at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3316) 03-31
>   20:45:44.131: E/AndroidRuntime(27445):    at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3153) 03-31
>   20:45:44.131: E/AndroidRuntime(27445):    at
>   android.view.View.draw(View.java:14856) 03-31 20:45:44.131:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(27445):  at
>   android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:467) 03-31
>   20:45:44.131: E/AndroidRuntime(27445):    at
>   com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.draw(PhoneWindow.java:2621)
>   03-31 20:45:44.131: E/AndroidRuntime(27445):  at
>   android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13744) 03-31 20:45:44.131:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(27445):  at
>   android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13786) 03-31 20:45:44.131:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(27445):  at
>   android.view.HardwareRenderer$GlRenderer.buildDisplayList(HardwareRenderer.java:1411)
>   03-31 20:45:44.131: E/AndroidRuntime(27445):  at
>   android.view.HardwareRenderer$GlRenderer.draw(HardwareRenderer.java:1359)
>   03-31 20:45:44.131: E/AndroidRuntime(27445):  at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw(ViewRootImpl.java:2672) 03-31
>   20:45:44.131: E/AndroidRuntime(27445):    at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl.performDraw(ViewRootImpl.java:2538) 03-31
>   20:45:44.131: E/AndroidRuntime(27445):    at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2154)
>   03-31 20:45:44.131: E/AndroidRuntime(27445):  at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1249) 03-31
>   20:45:44.131: E/AndroidRuntime(27445):    at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6364)
>   03-31 20:45:44.131: E/AndroidRuntime(27445):  at
>   android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:791)
>   03-31 20:45:44.131: E/AndroidRuntime(27445):  at
>   android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:591) 03-31
>   20:45:44.131: E/AndroidRuntime(27445):    at
>   android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:561) 03-31
>   20:45:44.131: E/AndroidRuntime(27445):    at
>   android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:777)
>   03-31 20:45:44.131: E/AndroidRuntime(27445):  at
>   android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730) 03-31
>   20:45:44.131: E/AndroidRuntime(27445):    at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92) 03-31
>   20:45:44.131: E/AndroidRuntime(27445):    at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176) 03-31 20:45:44.131:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(27445):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419) 03-31
>   20:45:44.131: E/AndroidRuntime(27445):    at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 03-31
>   20:45:44.131: E/AndroidRuntime(27445):    at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525) 03-31 20:45:44.131:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(27445):  at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1046)
>   03-31 20:45:44.131: E/AndroidRuntime(27445):  at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:862) 03-31
>   20:45:44.131: E/AndroidRuntime(27445):    at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: I believe the cleaner way of going about this would be to make your custom view not display anything if its "points" datastructure is empty, introduce a setter for the points datastructure on it, execute your db query and related stuff from the activity and call that setter on completion. If you use an `AsyncTask` for the database query, you can overlay your view with a progress bar pretty easily.

Comment: Is your activity relevant/mandatory for your custom view? I mean is there any reason that stops you for querying your db directly from your custom view?

Comment: Thank you for your answers! I try to draw nothing untill my calculations are done. Just a if-else like in the answer of rupps.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you should research a little about `onDraw()` lifecycle.

`onDraw` gets called at the beginning, and then will be called again everytime there is "*something*" to draw. How you tell a view it has "*something"* to draw? by calling "`invalidate`".

So on your `onDraw` *you do nothing at first*, if the points are not loaded.

When you have finished your calculations, just call `invalidate()` and `onDraw` will get called later on, *asynchronously*. By this time, in your `OnDraw` you'll detect that your calculations are ready, so **then** it's when you paint the stuff.

kind of:

```
 boolean myCalculationsAreReady=false;

 Paint mPaint=new Paint(); // to draw text "loading" ... (new edit). You have to call mPaint.setColor(Color.WHITE) or any color you want, the default would be Black.

 public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

      if (myCalculationsAreReady) {

            drawMyStuff (canvas);

      } else {

            // You don't have your calculations yet , just ignore, or paint a message ...
            drawDataNotReady(canvas);

      }

 }

 private void drawMyStuff (Canvas c) {
         // here you have your calculations available
         // time to draw !
 }

 // to make this view totally independent, you can create yourself a progress indicator here.
 // you can also put a standard progressbar at the parent level and notify the parent when
 // to show / hide it. I like this approach, because it's more efficient (you save one view)
 // but obviously you can use any fancy view you like over this one.

 private void drawDataNotReady (Canvas c) {
         c.drawText (0, c.getHeight() / 2, "Please wait while data is loading ...", mPaint); 
 }

 private void do_my_heavy_calculations () {

         // do all your calculations. 
         .
         .
         .             
         // when you are done:

         myCalculationsAreReady=true;

         invalidate(); // this will call onDraw
 }
```

When you understand how this works, and if your calculations are heavy, you definitely want to take them out of the UI thread. You can use a normal thread just like you ask, but then, the way to call "invalidate" is different:

```
view.postInvalidate();
```

this is used to invalidate views from outside the main UI thread (ie. your thread).

Also check out `AsyncTask` as a class to help writing asynchronous threads.

Comment: Thank you very much! This brings me a huge step forward. I first will try this and then I will use a Thread I think, since the calculations I do might take long if the database query gives me many data.

I just tried to set the visibility of a ProgressBar to true in the else block in the onDraw()-Method, but it doesn't work. I will edit my question and add some code and the errors.

Comment: onDraw() is not really the place to change visibilities. You want to keep onDraw as fast as possible. Change it elsewhere, for example, when you finish your data-decoding routine. Mind that a view's **onDraw** is called by the internals of Android and you don't want to pollute it changing visibilities of other views.

Comment: Sure, I accepted it allready. :)
So, in your example code you have the method "do_my_heavy_calculations", I tried to change the visibility there but  it seems that I shouldn't change any visibilities in the view class since it doesn't work. :-/

Should I maybe do the calculations in an other class?

Comment: Well it depends on how you structure the rest of stuff. Ideally, inside a **View** you **should** not touch other Views that are not children of it (although is of course technically possible), because that will make your View non-independent. You can for example define a Listener interface that will communicate the parent (ie.activity) when to hide a progressbar (kind of: MyView.loadData(new OnComplicatedDataReady { public void onComplicatedDataReady() { progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE); }});  OR do provide some logic in the onDraw to draw yourself manually a progressbar(line/image/circle

Comment: ... this has the advantage that your View will then work 100% by itself, without needing additional stuff. see my edit for these things ;)

Comment: And the reason why it is crashing is because you are calling the wrong **findViewById**: FindViewByid inside a View (**View.findViewById**) will look for a **children view** of this view (ergo will only work for ViewGroups (layouts, views that hold other views), while **<activity>.findViewById()** will look from the root view. That's what you'd need to do (((Activity)getContext()).findViewById()..., but then, you will be making this view dependent on a parent structure, something that is not good from the design point of view.

Comment: BTW-> on that beautiful stack trace you can see how the system calls your onDraw. Is a big trip, isnt it?

Comment: Thank you so much! I can't tell you how much you helped me there! I am now focusing on setting a LocationListener in a good way (trying to do my Custom one) and then fix the problem with your solution. As soon as I get 15 reputation I will vote up your post. :-)

Comment: I asked a new question, which is way more detailed and describes my current problem better. It's also a little bit different, since I have to have more than one additional thread. I hope you have time to read through this and help me:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22790021/correct-use-of-asynctasks-and-handle-objects-needed-by-a-view-and-activity