# Correct use of AsyncTasks and handle Objects needed by a View and Activity

Tags: java, android, mysql, android-asynctask

So I am currently writing an App and have a few questions about how to deal with AsyncTasks.
I describe my problem as detailed as I can. I have the following classes:

1. **MainActivity** - This Activity only executes `setContentView(R.layout.myLayout)` and
   creates an Object of my **CustomLocationListener**. The Layout contains a custom view and a `ProgressBar`.
2. **CustomLocationListener** - This is basically just a Class which implements `LocationListener` and has the default `LocationListener` methods. In addition to that I wrote a method to check which providers are enabled to prior use the `NETWORK_PROVIDER`.
3. **Display** - This is just an assisstant class. I use it only to get display metrics to calculate some things.
4. **MyCustomView** - This class extends the `View` class. It also has an Attribute of the type `Display` (my own class).

Now you should know everything important to my code. Well, my question now is, how to deal with AsyncTasks, since this are the steps the App should go through:

1. Get the current location of the users device
2. Execute some queries to a database server (mysql) and save them non persistent (the data consists of city names)
3. Calculate the distance between the users location and the cities in the database
4. Do some other calculations to figure out the positions where to draw on the screen
5. Draw everything

On top of that I would like to implement a progress bar, which should be active untill all calculations are done and the drawing phase begins.
So, I'm kinda confused where to code what. I mean, both calculations (step 3. and 4.) have to know about each other. The calculation of step 4 needs the results of the calculation of step 3. And my Activity class should also know about the state of the calculations, since I have to make the ProgressBar invisible when I start to draw.

I hope I was detailed enough and I appreciate your help!

Comment: I could just execute all needed Threads in the Activity class and after all calculations are done I could make the ProgressBar invisible. But how can I then start to draw? I mean, the onDraw() starts immediately when I open the Activity. I could use a If-Else-Block to check a boolean if the calculations are done. But how could I invalidate the view in a thread outside the view class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, from the [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) docs you can gather this:

> When an asynchronous task is executed, the task goes through 4 steps:
>
> 1. onPreExecute(), invoked on the UI thread before the task is executed. This step is normally used to setup the task, for instance
>      by showing a progress bar in the user interface.
> 2. doInBackground(Params...), invoked on the background thread immediately after onPreExecute() finishes executing. This step is used
>      to perform background computation that can take a long time. The
>      parameters of the asynchronous task are passed to this step. The
>      result of the computation must be returned by this step and will be
>      passed back to the last step. This step can also use
>      publishProgress(Progress...) to publish one or more units of progress.
>      These values are published on the UI thread, in the
>      onProgressUpdate(Progress...) step.
> 3. onProgressUpdate(Progress...), invoked on the UI thread after a call to publishProgress(Progress...). The timing of the execution is
>      undefined. This method is used to display any form of progress in the
>      user interface while the background computation is still executing.
>      For instance, it can be used to animate a progress bar or show logs in
>      a text field.
> 4. onPostExecute(Result), invoked on the UI thread after the background computation finishes. The result of the background
>      computation is passed to this step as a parameter.

So what I would suggest for you is to use two AsyncTasks to do your geo and server (one for each) work in the `doInBackground(Params...)` method and return the value to your MainActivity in the `onPostExecute(Result)` method.  Also, keep your MainActivity aware of the progress by using the `onProgressUpdate(Progress..)` method.

When they are done, you can choose to use another AsyncTask to do the calculations if they stall the UI thread noticeably.  Use the same method of execution for it.

When this is all done you are ready to draw a view... (I think is what you're saying)

Have a default view load before you start the calculations that says "Loading..." or whatever.  Have another view that is not visible ready for when you are ready to display your calculated things and just set it visible when it is ready to be drawn on.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I think this is going to work. I have implemented an AsyncTask to get the current location so far. I just have problems with the visibility of my custom view. Even if I set the visibility in the xml-file to "gone" it's still visible.

Comment: Hmm. In your custom view, are you overriding the parent class method 'setVisibility(...)' and not calling 'super.setVisibility(...)'?

Comment: No, I tried this but it didn't work... I tried something else now. I created a reference of the View in my Activity and a Reference of the View in my AsyncTask. The constructor of the AsyncTask initializes his reference to the View with the reference of the View in the Activity. I tried then to call postInvalidate() on the reference in my onPostExecute()-method, but I still get a NullPointerException. :/

Comment: So, you created the 'customView' class and added it to you activity via the activity's xml-layout.  Now you are getting a reference to that view in the activity using ...CustomView cv = (CustomView)findViewById(R.id.customViewId).  It this correct?

Comment: Exactly. I don't know why this should throw a NullPointerException.

Comment: It is a bit difficult to say without seeing the code.  Sorry I couldn't be more help.  =/